# Fully GPU accelerated (decoding,deinterlacing,scaling,encoding) HLS variable stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, transcoding, nvenc, cuvid

I'm trying to create a variable HLS MBR live stream using ffmpeg, which will be fully accelerated at the GPU level. This means accelerated decoding, deinterlacing, scaling and encoding. Here is my broken example ...

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -vsync 0 -i "udp://@239.250.4.152:1234?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,split=3[v1][v2][v3],[v1]copy[v1out],[v2]scale_npp=1280:720[v2out],[v3]scale_npp=720:405[v3out]" \
-map [v1out] -c:v:0 hevc_nvenc -b:v:0 4000k -g 48 \
-map [v2out] -c:v:1 hevc_nvenc -b:v:0 3000k -g 48 \
-map [v3out] -c:v:2 hevc_nvenc -b:v:0 2000k -g 48 \
-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 128k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 64k -ac 2 \
-f hls \
-hls_playlist_type event \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_time $seglen \
-hls_list_size $numsegs \
-hls_flags delete_segments+independent_segments \
-hls_segment_filename "$dst/stream_%v/$segments" \
-hls_base_url "$url" \
-master_pl_name "$dst/$index" \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
"$dst/$index"
```

Note: My graphics card can handle more than 2 concurrent encodings.
I'm getting a classic error "Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_split_1' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'".

Is my goal real? Or what is the proper way to use the GPU in this scenario as efficiently as possible? Thanks for the help.

```
Stream mapping:
   Stream # 0: 3 (h264_cuvid) -> yadif_cuda (graph 0)
   copy (graph 0) -> Stream # 0: 0 (h264_nvenc)
   scale_npp (graph 0) -> Stream # 0: 1 (h264_nvenc)
   scale_npp (graph 0) -> Stream # 0: 2 (h264_nvenc)
   Stream # 0: 4 -> # 0: 3 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
   Stream # 0: 4 -> # 0: 4 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
   Stream # 0: 4 -> # 0: 5 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a working solution. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to avoid moving between VRAM and RAM yet, due to the split filter, which duplicates the video track.

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0  -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "udp://@239.250.4.152:1234?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1" \
-filter_complex "[0:v]yadif_cuda=0:-1:0,hwdownload,format=nv12,split=3[v1][v2][v3]; [v1]copy[v1out]; [v2]hwupload,scale_npp=1280:720[v2out]; [v3]hwupload,scale_npp=720:405[v3out]" \
-map [v1out] -c:v:0 h264_nvenc -b:v:0 4000k -g 48 \
-map [v2out] -c:v:1 h264_nvenc -b:v:0 3000k -g 48 \
-map [v3out] -c:v:2 h264_nvenc -b:v:0 2000k -g 48 \
-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 128k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 64k -ac 2 \
-f hls \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_time $seglen \
-hls_list_size $numsegs \
-hls_flags delete_segments+independent_segments \
-hls_segment_filename "$dst/stream_%v/$segments" \
-master_pl_name "$index" \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" \
"$dst/stream_%v/mystream.m3u8"
```